# How would I be able to get the foreign key name in another table using nested eager loading with eloquent and laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I currently have 3 models `Specie` `Type` `User`. I want to be able to get the name of the last modified user in relation to the Specie model

The relationships are as follows

```
Class Specie extends Model {
   public function type()
   {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Type', 'type_id');
   }

   public function user()
   {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
   }
}

Class Type extends Model {
   public function specie()
   {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Specie', 'type_id');
   }
}

Class User extends Model {
   public function specie()
   {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Specie', 'user_id');
   }
}
```

I have tried this

```
Class Specie extends Model {
    public function lastModified()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'last_modified_by');
    }
}
```

And then used the below code

```
$this->type->with(['specie.lastModified' => function ($query) use 
        ($userId) {
            $query->where('user_id', $userId);
        }])->get();
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work

However, by using this code

```
$this->type->with(['specie' => function ($query) use ($userId) {
            $query->where('user_id', $userId);
        }])->get();
```

I am able to get this:

```
"id": 1,
"type": "Halo",
"created_at": "2019-07-20 13:02:53",
"updated_at": "2019-07-20 13:02:53",
"specie": [
  {
    "id": 6,
    "user_id": 1,
    "type_id": 1,
    "note": "et",
    "last_modified_by": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "user_id": 1,
    "type_id": 2,
    "note": "sa",
    "last_modified_by": 2,
  },
]
```

However, what I want to get is the name of the last modified person name which is the primary key in the User model and the foreign key in the Specie model

This is what I expect to get:

```
"id": 1,
"type": "Halo",
"created_at": "2019-07-20 13:02:53",
"updated_at": "2019-07-20 13:02:53",
"specie": [
  {
    "id": 6,
    "user_id": 1,
    "type_id": 1,
    "note": "et",
    "last_modified_by": 1,
    "user": [
        {
         "id": 1,
         "user": 'gerrard'
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "user_id": 1,
    "type_id": 2,
    "note": "sa",
    "last_modified_by": 2,
    "user": [
         {
           "id": 2,
           "user": 'chris'
         }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `with()` inside the `with()` should do it:

```
$this->type->with(['specie' => function ($query) use ($userId) {
    $query->where('user_id', $userId);
    $query->with('lastModified');
}])->get();
```

The only difference is the relation key is not named `"user"` but rather name of the relationship (`"last_modified"`).

```
"id": 1,
"type": "Halo",
"created_at": "2019-07-20 13:02:53",
"updated_at": "2019-07-20 13:02:53",
"specie": [
    {
        "id": 6,
        "user_id": 1,
        "type_id": 1,
        "last_modified_by": 2,
        "note": "et",
        "last_modified": {
            "id": 2
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: How can I get specific columns for the lastModified.


`$this->type->with(['specie' => function ($query) use ($userId) {
    $query->where('user_id', $userId);
    $query->with('lastModified')->select('id', 'name');
}])->get();`

Comment: The easiest would be `$query->with('lastModified:id,name');`. An alternative is to make the second `with()` a nested function and place a `select()` inside,